# url is not registered http //schemas.android.com/apk/res/android

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Empece a trabajar con recyclerview y cardview y luego tuve que poner una dependencia y cuando estaba sincronizado el build me mando este error, ya borre los activitys y clases que use, también borre las dependencias que no necesitaba y actualice el android studio y no funciono :

> url is not registered http //schemas.android.com/apk/res/android

```
manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.luisfrancisco.sinfilarregional
```

Answer (score 1):

En mi caso simplemente lo solucioné cambiando la versión del SDK. Inicialmente tenia el proyecto en la API 27, y cuando importé el proyecto en otro PC tenia la API 28 por defecto y me dió este error.

Al volverlo a la API 27 se solucionó

```
Project Structure -> Platform Settings -> SDKs
```

Answer (score 0):

El mensaje mostrado es :

> uri is not registered http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android

El problema es que el archivo en cuestión no puede encontrar el namespace ya que se encuentra en una ubicación incorrecta.

En el caso del archivo Manifest.xml, este se debe encontrar dentro de:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En el caso de layouts, debe estar dentro de el folder `/res`, recuerda que los layout deben estar dentro de `/res/layout`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]